# is there a dashboard html ui library?

Tags: html, dashboard

I would like to bootstrap a new dashboard, i'm wondering if there is already an open source dashboard html ui library which is similiar to twitter's bootstrap that I can use in my development.

Comment: Are you looking for charts and graphs, or fancier images like meters and speedometers?

Comment: i'm looking for an existing dashboard structure that i can use.

Answer (score 7):

check this:

preview:

http://mathew-davies.co.uk/admin-template/dashboard.html

download:

https://github.com/ThePixelDeveloper/admin-template

[image]

good luck!!

Comment: yeah, what i really need is an admin interface, this one seems close, well is there a better looking one than this?

Comment: Awesome that is exactly what i want

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [This page intentionally left ugly](http://eksith.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/jquery-ui-dashboard/) which shows and explains a [jQuery UI dashboard demo](http://eksith.com/experiments/dashboard/). Would this fit your requirement?

[Please read](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/index.html) about [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) if you are not already familiar with it. It might be useful in your project.